# SOAP API Get Cookie

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soapui, zeep

I'm using a SOAP API to get an authentication key with a cookie that is suppose to be returned.

```
from zeep import Client
client = Client("AuthenticationService.xml")
result = client.service.ValidateUser(username, password, "")
result
```

However with the result, I am getting a Boolean of True but no Cookie that contains the authentication key.

From the below picture, you can see that the same request using SoapUI returns a cookie. I'm wondering how I can do this in Python.

[image: SoapUI Software Response]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to handle `cookie`, we must use `requests.Session` for the `transport`.

So a simple use case would look like this for you:

```
from zeep import Client
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
# disable TLS verification
session.verify = False

transport = Transport(session=session)

client = Client("AuthenticationService.xml", transport=transport)

result = client.service.ValidateUser(username, password, "")

# then check cookie
client.transport.session.cookies
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for accepting the answer.